# Multiple Group By and Count in LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

I am facing one simple question here and since I am new in LINQ, I really need someone help.

I have a SQL query to sum the amount based on `Client ID`,  `CommissionName` and `Date` only from a `DateTime`.

Here is the SQL query :

```
SELECT 
    ClientId, CommisionName,
    CAST(Date AS DATE) DateOnly, 
    SUM(Amount)
FROM 
    [MyDB].[dbo].[Commission] 
GROUP BY
    ClientId, CAST(Date AS DATE), CommisionName
```

What I got for grouping in LINQ is :

```
var data = from c in await _context.Commission.ToListAsync() 
           group c by new
                   {
                       c.CommisionName,
                       c.ClientId,
                       c.Date,
                   } into gcs
           select new
                   {
                       ClientId = gcs.Key.ClientId,
                       CommissionName = gcs.Key.CommisionName,
                       Date = gcs.Key.Date,
                   };
```

But I still don't have a reference if I need to summarize the `Amount`.

Please I need someone reference.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `gcs.Sum(x => x.Amount)` to perform the sum of the `Amount`.

Note that your current query will query all the records and perform group on the memory side.

To perform the query with group on the database side, the LINQ query should be below:

```cs
var data = await (from c in _context.Commission 
                   group c by new
                   {
                       c.CommisionName,
                       c.ClientId,
                       c.Date.Date,
                   } into gcs
                   select new
                   {
                       ClientId = gcs.Key.ClientId,
                       CommissionName = gcs.Key.CommisionName,
                       Date = gcs.Key.Date,
                       Amount = gcs.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                   }
                   ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! but one more advice please, how to group it by Date only instead of DateTime ?

Comment: You should use `c.Date.Date`, the LINQ query will convert it as Date in SQL query.